# How can I take an input from an entry widget and enter it into a sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

I've been reading that using get() is the best way to do this, but I'm not sure how to use it, and other answers haven't been helpful to me.
The following is the main part of the code. I'm using python 3.6, tkinter and sqlite3.

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Tk, Button, Label, Entry, N, S, E, W
from tkinter import TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT, END, ALL

top=Tk()
top.geometry("320x225")
top.title('dvd rentals')
medium_font=('Veranda', 10)
textFrame=Frame(top)

loaneeID=Label()
loaneeID=Label(top,font=medium_font,text='Loanee ID ')
loaneeID.grid(row=2, column=1)
entry1=Entry(textFrame)
entry1=Entry(top, bd = 5, font=medium_font, width=25)
entry1.grid(row=2, column=2)

submit_button = tk.Button(top, text='Add Item', width=8,
                            command=lambda: add_item(top))
submit_button.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=E, pady=20, padx=20)

top.mainloop()

def main():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('dvd.db')
    c=conn.cursor()

def tableCreate(c):
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS loanee (loaneeID int, name text, email text)')
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dvd (dvdID int, name text)')
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS loan (loaneeID int, dvdID int, start date text, end date text)')

def insertValues(c, loanee, dvd, loan):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO loanee VALUES (?,?,?)',loanee)
    c.execute('INSERT INTO dvd VALUES (?,?)',dvd)
    c.execute('INSERT INTO loan VALUES (?,?,?,?)',loan)

    tableCreate(c)

    insertValues(c, loanee, dvd, loan)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
main()
```

My aim is that user will enter their ID (and other entries), which they can add to the database using the designated submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `get()` method of the `Entry` widget to get the current contents of the widget.

You need to add the `add_item()` function to your code, then get the user's entry using code similar to this:

```
def add_item():
    loanee_id = entry1.get()
    print(loanee_id)
```

Then you need to call your SQL functions to insert the data.

Notice that there are a few problems with your code, the first is that the code after the line `top.mainloop()` will not be executed until you close the Tk window. Also the logic of the SQL functions is incorrect.

You should read up on how to organise your Tk application to use classes because this will make your code more manageable and easier to work with.

Comment: So this would need to be added before the button, but withing the rest of the tkinter stuff, right?

Comment: Also, using the code above results in an error saying loanee_id is not defined.